# DLL Compilation Error (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, dll

We have a webserver with two versions of the AjaxControlKit on it. Im getting the following error when hitting certain pages on a specific web application.

> The type
>   'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender'
>   exists in both
>   'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\AjaxControlToolkit\3.0.30930.28736__28f01b0e84b6d53e\AjaxControlToolkit.dll'
>   and
>   'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\AjaxControlToolkit\3.0.30512.20315__28f01b0e84b6d53e\AjaxControlToolkit.dll'

The web project Im running has a reference to the x.30930 dll, and it also has

```
<add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.28736, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
```

Specified in the web.config.

For the life of me I cant find out why it wants to try running x.30512.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have the x.30512 assembly in the bin folder?

Comment: is there a GAC policy concerning that assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Aaargh there was a reference to it in the 'global' web.config (in the c:\windows\microsoft.net\ folder